# HTML5 Canvas viewport

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

how would I go about making a camera that follows a player in a game? Everyone example I look doesn't seem to explain what each thing does and why, so what I'm asking if possible is if someone could make me a quick example of one and explain why each part is there any why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A world is usually bigger than the window, so a view shows specific area of the whole world.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eLrjk/3/)

```
/* vX, vY is position of viewport
   vWidth, vHeight is size of viewport
   In this case position of viewport is (0,0) and its size is 5x5 */

var vX = 0,
    vY = 0,
    vWidth = 5,
    vHeight = 5;

/* color is used to draw a world map. 
   Map is a matrix which stores map information. Length of each row is width of 
   world map and number of rows is height of world map. Each value refer to color.*/

var color = ["#008000","#DAA520","#008080"];
var map = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0],
            [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
            [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1],
            [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2],
            [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2],
            [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2],
            [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2],
            [0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2]];

$(document).ready(function(){
    /* get canvas element and get its context. Everything is drawn on context. */
    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    /* canvas is a viewport. I'll set block size to 32x32px, so viewport size is      
       160x160px */
    canvas.width = 160;
    canvas.height = 160;

    /* addEventlist */
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
        switch (e.which) {
        case 37:
            if (vX > 0) vX--;
            break;
        case 38:
            if (vY > 0) vY--;
            break;
        case 39:
            if (vX< 10-vWidth) vX++;
            break;
        case 40:
            if (vY< 10-vHeight) vY++;
            break;
        }
        draw();
    }, false);
    draw();

    function draw(){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        for(var x =0 ; x < vWidth;x++){
            for(var y=0;y<vHeight;y++){
                theX = x*32;
                theY = y*32;
                ctx.fillStyle=color[map[y+vY][x+vX]];
                ctx.fillRect(theX,theY,32,32);
            }
        }
    }

});
```